# Flask-Migrate having issue with enum class in models

Tags: python, flask, enums, sqlalchemy, alembic

Using flask-migrate before I was able to create enums by using flask-sqlalchemy's db.Enum and entering the values in as strings like so.

```
reservation_status = db.Enum('pending', 'confirmed, name='reservation_status_enum')
```

I decided to start using enum classes like the following. According to the [sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html?highlight=enum#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) works fine.

```
class Status(enum.Enum):
    pending = 'pending'
    confirmed = 'confirmed'
    rejected = 'rejected'
    abandoned = 'abandoned'

reservation_status = db.Enum(Status, name='reservation_status_enum')

class Reservation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reservations'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(reservation_status, default=Status.pending)
    ...
```

When I try to use the migrate command I get an invalid syntax error in the generated code as follows. The error is exactly what was written to the file.

```
    sa.Column('status', sa.Enum(<enum 'Status'>, name='reservation_status_enum'), nullable=True),
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: According to your link, support for `enum.Enum` was added to SQLAlchemy in version 1.1. The most recent (non pre-release) version of SQLAlchemy is 1.0.14. I wouldn't expect Alembic to be updated until after SQLAlchemy 1.1 is released.

Comment: You know, I was wrapped up in the code I forgot about versioning. That would make sense. Seems like for now I am stuck with string enums. Thank you @dim. I am using sqlite for testing danidee

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user @dim, I was able to resolve the issue by upgrading just sqlalchemy to beta 1.1.0b3. As is most cases, it was user error(me).

All i did was

```
pip uninstall sqlalchemy
pip install sqlalchemy==1.1.0b3
```